# codedeploy user profile - Windows

Tags: aws-code-deploy, jfrog-cli

Does AWS codedeploy run as any specific user profile on Windows servers? 
I am trying to run a jfrog.exe cli to download from a remote Artifactory repository, using a prebuilt user ID and password which is dependent on ~/users/{user id}/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf

How would codedeploy be able to source a .jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf ?

Comment: I figured this out - on Windows, within c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile - a .jfrog folder is actually created

Answer (score 1):

The CodeDeploy agent is configured as service to use the SYSTEM account as logon identity. Because of that all processes execute as the SYSTEM user. As a word of caution, the process cmd and powershell processes launched by agent are in 32bit mode. This is important to understand because

- Powershell 32bit and 64bit have differences, especially when there is a dependency to installed modules.
- Some things are different with the SYSTEM user. For example the temp directory is not the same as with for every other user.

Knowing this helps a lot when trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy now only support repo in S3 or Github. Where does your repo exists?

Comment: The purpose of using jfrog-cli is to download the artifact from an artifact repository.